# Ignore spaces in for Loop while printing file name?

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames

I am trying to get files having size greater than 1k and with an txt extension my code is as follows :

```
files=$(find foldername -size +1k -name \*.txt -exec {} \;)

for item in $files
do 
echo $item
done
```

But I am getting unexpected output as given below. Please help !!!

```
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 1: Hello: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 2: This: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 3: In: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 4: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 5: User: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 6: -s: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 7: -d: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 8: -t: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 9: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 10: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 11: Hello: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 12: This: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 13: In: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 14: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 15: User: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 16: -s: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 17: -d: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 18: -t: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 19: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 20: Hello: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 21: This: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 22: In: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 23: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 24: User: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 25: -s: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 26: -d: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy - Copy.txt: line 27: -t: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 1: Hello: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 2: This: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 3: In: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 4: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 5: User: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 6: -s: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 7: -d: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 8: -t: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 9: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 10: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 11: Hello: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 12: This: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 13: In: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 14: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 15: User: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 16: -s: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 17: -d: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 18: -t: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 19: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 20: Hello: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 21: This: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 22: In: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 23: $'\r': command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 24: User: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 25: -s: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 26: -d: command not found
DEST/sample - Copy.txt: line 27: -t: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `-exec` is to what you mean to do.
(The option `-exec` executes a file not read it)

The simple solution to print the filenames that match find options is:

```
find foldername -size +1k -name \*.txt -print
```

---

If you need the names to be assigned to a variable, you need more.
To be able to deal with spaces in file names that result from the command `find`, the option `-print0` is the usual solution:

```
find foldername -size +1k -name \*.txt -print0
```

However, to be able to read the results into a bash variable, is not easy.
There is a long explanation in [this excellent Greg's wiki page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

```
#!/bin/bash
unset a
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    a+=( "$file" )        # or however you want to process each file
done < <(find foldername -size +1k -name \*.txt -print0)

printf 'filename=%s\n' "${a[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks for so much detailed answer. It really help me alot

Answer (score 1):

The apparent problem: the find-command is doing an `-exec {}`, which attempts to execute each file which was found (the source of most of the error messages).  Perhaps you meant just `-print`, e.g.,

```
files=$(find foldername -size +1k -name \*.txt -print)
```

You will also get into trouble with the list, if it happens to find files with blanks in their names — but you will see that once you find the files correctly.

There are several ways to do this; here's one making little change to your script:

```
find foldername -size +1k -name \*.txt -print | \
while IFS= read -r item
do 
echo "$item"
done
```

Comment: Now I am not getting an error but unfortunately there is a space in my file name due to which for loop I am getting in correct result. I have only 2 files in my folder which matches the condition but I am getting 8 result due to spaces in file name

Comment: My file names are :
sample - Copy - Copy.txt and
sample - Copy.txt
and I am getting following result : DEST/sample ; - ; Copy ; - ; Copy.txt ; DEST/sample ;  - ; Copy.txt

Answer (score 0):

With `-exec {} \;`, you're telling `find` to execute each of the files that it finds as a command. It seems that you meant to print out the file names, so say that: `-print`. But [that breaks if the file names contain whitespace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). It's generally a bad idea to parse the output of `ls` or `find`; only do it if you're absolutely sure that it's impossible for the file names to contain whitespace or other special characters.

The safe way to act on `find` results is to make `find` trigger the action. If you need to use some shell constructs (multiple commands, `if`, variable expansion, pipes, etc.), invoke a shell. Pass the file name as an argument to that shell.

```
find … -exec sh -c '
  echo "$0"
' {} \;
```

You can make this faster by invoking a shell for a batch of files instead of one for each file.

```
find … -exec sh -c '
  for item do
    echo "$item"
  done
' sh {} +
```